# How to treat List<Task<T>> polymorphically to handle exceptions

Tags: c#, polymorphism, task-parallel-library, .net-5, code-duplication

I'm trying to create one method that logs the inner exceptions of a list of tasks. The problem is that in some places I have just (A) `List<Task>` and in other places I have (B) `List<Task<Something>>`. I tried to create a method that accepts A but then the compiler does not accept calls to that method with B, so I call B as "MultipleTasksExceptionHandler(B as A)" but inside the method I receive null. So I had to create to almost identical methods like below and they work but is there any other way to avoid this code duplication?

```
    public static void MultipleTasksExceptionHandler<T>(IList<Task<T>> tasks, ILogger logger)
    {
        var exceptions = tasks.Where(task => task.IsFaulted).SelectMany(x => x.Exception.InnerExceptions);

        foreach (var exception in exceptions)
        {
            logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
        }
    }

    public static void MultipleTasksExceptionHandler(IList<Task> tasks, ILogger logger)
    {
        var exceptions = tasks.Where(task => task.IsFaulted).SelectMany(x => x.Exception.InnerExceptions);

        foreach (var exception in exceptions)
        {
            logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a covariant collection, such as `IEnumerable<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>`, rather than `IList<T>`:

```
public void MultipleTasksExceptionHandler(IEnumerable<Task> tasks, ILogger logger)
{
    var exceptions = tasks.Where(task => task.IsFaulted).SelectMany(x => x.Exception.InnerExceptions);

    foreach (var exception in exceptions)
    {
        logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
    } 
}
```

It's correct that you can't assign an object of type `IList<Task<T>>` to a variable of type `IList<Task>`. If this were allowed, you would be able to do `list.Add(Task.CompletedTask)`, and insert a non-generic `Task` into your `IList<Task<T>>`, which would obviously be wrong.

For example:

```
IList<Task<int>> listOfTaskOfT = new List<Task<int>>();

// This isn't allowed
IList<Task> listOfTask = listOfTaskOfT;

// ... if it was, you'd be able to do this:
listOfTask.Add(new Task());
Task<int> task = listOfTaskOfT[0];
// But that item is a Task, not a Task<int>. Oops!
```

However, this isn't a problem if you can only ever take things *out* of your collection. This is called [generic covariance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/covariance-and-contravariance), and generic interfaces can mark themselves as covariant using the `out` keyword. [`IEnumerable<out T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ienumerable-1?view=net-5.0) and [`IReadOnlyList<out T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=net-5.0) both do this.

You're then allowed to do things like:

```
IEnumerable<Task> tasks = new List<Task<T>>();
```

... provided that all of the generic type arguments involved are reference types.

(A similar feature exists for generic "contravariant" interfaces where you can only ever add items, using the `in` keyword).

---

You can get similar functionality using generics:

```
public void MultipleTasksExceptionHandler<T>(IList<T> tasks, ILogger logger) where T : Task
{
   var exceptions = tasks.Where(task => task.IsFaulted).SelectMany(x => x.Exception.InnerExceptions);

    foreach (var exception in exceptions)
    {
        logger.LogError(exception, exception.Message);
    } 
}
```

Here, you're prevented from adding a `Task` into an `IList<Task<Whatever>>` by virtue of the fact that `T` is `Task<Whatever>`. This isn't needed in your case, but can be useful if you do actually need to insert items into your collection.

Comment: +1 for [`Task.IsFaulted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.isfaulted?view=net-5.0). I've seen `AggregateException` before, but this looks cleaner.

Comment: @DakotaMethvin That's just the code in the question as is...

Comment: Indeed, I'm not passing judgement on what the OP is doing inside their method, just answering their specific question

Comment: @Servy So it is, I'm blind.

Comment: Calling it MultipleTasksExceptionHandler(processTasks, _logger); Throws: The type arguments for method 'MultipleTasksExceptionHandler<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>>, ILogger)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly. So I add the type MultipleTasksExceptionHandler<Task>(processTasks, _logger); and it throws cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<System.Threading.Tasks.Task>>'

Comment: @user33276346 [See them compiling and working here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/UAep5F). I notice you've written `Handler<T>(IEnumerable<Task<T>>, ...)` which isn't something that's in my answer. Please make sure you read my answer carefully

Answer (score 0):

You're only ever iterating over the tasks, never manipulating the collection in any other way.  You shouldn't be accepting an `IList` if you don't actually need its functionality.  Accept an `IEnumerable<Task>` instead, and as it's covariant your problem goes away entirely.